# Node.js GET request taking too long

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I'm trying to get simple GET request in POSTMAN, and request is taking forever to execute. I'm trying to reach simple endpoint and there is no response. I am using latest stable version of Node.js (16.14.0) and this is my code:

```
var Express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


//Middleware

var app = Express()
app.use(bodyParser.json)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))


//Spajanje na MONGODB

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var CONNECTION_STRING = 
"mongodb+srv://vimartinez:@hotelscluster.u3xej.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority"
var DATABASE = "testdb"
var database;

//Spajanje na server(port) + na MONGODB

app.listen(49146, () => {
console.log("Server je pokrenut!")
MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_STRING,{useNewUrlParser:true}, (error, client) => {
    database=client.db(DATABASE)
    console.log("MongoDB connected!")
})
})


app.get('/', (request,response) => {
response.send('HEllllooo')
 })

app.get('/api/department', (request, response) => {
database.collection("Department").find({}).toArray((error, result) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
res.send(result)
})
})
```

I cannot reach even http://localhost:49146 in Postman, this is result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sIM1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using middleware incorrectly

Instead of `app.use(bodyParser.json)` try

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```